# Does MPI_Probe return as soon as possible?

Tags: mpi

Suppose my MPI process is waiting for a very big message, and I am waiting for it with `MPI_Probe`. Is it correct to suppose the `MPI_Probe` call will return as soon as the process receives the first notice of the message from the network (like a header with the size or something like)?

I.e., will it return much faster than if I was waiting for the message with `MPI_Recv`, because it wouldn't need to receive the full message?

Comment: Can you post code to give more detail regarding your intended usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard is fairly silent on this matter (MPI-3.0, section 3.8.1), but does offer this:

> The MPI implementation of MPI_PROBE and MPI_IPROBE needs to guarantee progress:
>   if a call to MPI_PROBE has been issued by a process, and a send that matches the probe
>   has been initiated by some process, then the call to MPI_PROBE will return, unless the
>   message is received by another concurrent receive operation (that is executed by another
>   thread at the probing process).

Since both MPI_PROBE and MPI_RECV will engage the progress engine, I would doubt there is much difference between the two functions, aside from a memory copy.  By engaging the progress engine, it's likely the message will be received (internally) by the MPI implementation.  The last step of copying it into the user's buffer can be avoided in MPI_PROBE.

If you are worried about performance, then avoiding MPI_ANY_SOURCE and MPI_ANY_TAG if possible will help most implementations (certainly MPICH) take a faster path.